# What is the difference between these 2 queries (end Result)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested in if and what the difference is between these 2 queries are:

This one has SELECT TOP 1

```
UPDATE tblTemp SET [SOH] = (Select top 1 (tblstock.[Stock On Hand (Base UOM)])
 FROM tblstock
 WHERE tblTEMP.[ID] = tblstock.[ID])
```

and this one does not

```
UPDATE tblTemp SET [SOH] = (Select tblstock.[Stock On Hand (Base UOM)])
FROM tblstock 
WHERE tblTEMP.[ID] = tblstock.[ID]
```

The first one affects more rows.

So my question is:  Are they doing the same thing?

Comment: You should get error with the second query, did you try it ?

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir only if the subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: They both have issues. The first one is using top with no order by and the second one will crash if the subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: @Tanner . . . Without a `FROM` clause it is impossible for the subquery to return more than one row.  The second query does not generate an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's hard to read such awful SQL and make sense of it, even still my comment is valid with what you've stated.

Comment: The second one runs fine, there will only ever by 1 row as the UNION is removing the duplicates @Md.SumanKabir

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Still learning

Comment: @Tanner the sql itself isn't all that awful, it is that unbelievably bad column name "Stock On Hand (Base UOM)" that turns this into an eyesore.

Comment: @SeanLange if you have to read it 3 or 4 times to try to understand it... :-)

Comment: @Tanner 100000% agreed. That column turns somewhat poorly formatted sql into something abysmal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the second is more appropriately written as:

```
UPDATE tblTemp
    SET [SOH] = tblstock.[Stock On Hand (Base UOM)]
    FROM tblstock 
    WHERE tblTEMP.[ID] = tblstock.[ID];
```

(There is no reason to have a subquery with no `FROM` clause; it is a wasted `SELECT`.)

Second, they do not do the same thing.  The first will set `SOH` to `NULL` if there is no match.  The second will not change the existing value.

This ignores what happens when there are multiple matches.  SQL Server does not specify which row is used for the update.  So, even the same query might produce different results on different runs on the same data.

Comment: Thank you, so If I understand you correctly if there was no existing value they would result in the same thing?

Comment: @MarkBlackburn . . . If all the values matched exactly once between the two tables, then they would have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, your sub-query includes your where clause. So it will be updating all in the tblTemp table.

The second query has the where clause supplied outside of the sub-query, so applies this where to the tblTemp table.